# What makes pizza flour different from normal flour?

Tags: flour, pizza

The stores where I live do not sell pizza flour. How can I make stretchy pizza flour from raw or all purpose flour? You should be able to spin it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, you can make a stretchy dough from almost any flour, but stretchy isn't necessarily the only characteristic you are looking for.  Firstly, which style of pizza are you making? The next question you want to ask yourself is what final result you are looking for.  Then, see which ingredients, tools, and techniques are available to achieve (or get close to) those results.  You will not be able to convert AP into some other type of flour, but there is often the opportunity for mail order for specialized ingredients. Additionally, [Serious Eats did a comparison of flours](https://slice.seriouseats.com/2011/06/the-pizza-lab-on-flour-foams-and-dough.html) in pizza dough.  It might be instructive to have a look.  To troubleshoot the dough you are making, search this site.  If you don't find help, create a new question with your recipe and process.

Comment: Read the Serious Eats artical that Moscafi recommend. 

I use King Arthur Bread Flour to make pizza.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of pizza flour, you just use all purpose flour, could be whole wheat if you want. It's really simple and straight forward, flour, water, yeast, olive oil,  pinch of sugar, and a little salt. King Arthur recipe, but there all pretty much the same. [1](https://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/pizza-crust-recipe)

Comment: Sorry,  but recipes for pizza dough differ considerably, depending on style.  ...and type of flour has a significant impact.